# How can I remove values from array with lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to remove the undefined values from this array:
[undefined, "een", "twee", undefined]. The collection is an object like this:

```
{container:{id:1},container2:{id:2},container3:{pid:2}}
```

This does not work:

```
_.remove(_.map(collection,'id'),"undefined")
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `undefined` and `"undefined"` are not the same thing. `_.remove(_.map(collection,'id'), undefined);` works. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Waarom lodash, array.filter werkt goed

Comment: `.filter` also removes other untruthy values like `false` and `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `_.without(_.map(collection, 'id'), undefined)`.

`_.remove()` returns the removed items.

Answer (score 0):

For an array, you can use
`_.compact([NaN, 1, 0, 2, null, 5, undefined, 4])`
to remove all falsey values, which will produce `[1, 2, 5, 4]`

[_.compact](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#compact) docs

In case your collection is an object, you can use

`_.pickBy({foo: 'bar', baz: undefined}, _.identity)`

to achieve a similar result: `{foo: 'bar'}`.

Of course, you can always use any other function instead of `_.identity` if you have more complex logic.

I would also suggest looking at [_.remove()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#remove) depending on your needs.

Also, everything can be achieved with `_.filter`,`_.map`,`_.reduce`.

Good luck!